# Remove weird black box from html header

Tags: html, css

Work asked me to do some work on this older app that no one really manages anymore. One thing that the client had asked for was to remove this black dot in the top right of the header:
[image]

Here is the code for that:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #F6861F"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #DD1372"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #41AD49"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #00AAC0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #D32027"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #F49AC1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #EBB700"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #00ADE4">&#9632;</div>
</div>
```

First of all, what even is this in the last col? `&#9632;` If I remove that the entire colored row there disappears all together. How can I get rid of that black dot? Is there not a cleaner way to do this in the first place?

Comment: If you type "&#9632;" into google, you'll see what it is. It's the character for a black square

Comment: Well then why does removing it make the colored row no longer visible?

Comment: You can use `&nbsp;` instead of `&#9632;` or set height to `col` element.

Comment: Bless you for this @ChanHyeok-Im why don't you post an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @ColePerry It's really kind of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&nbsp;` instead of `&#9632;` or set `height` to col element.

- Using `&nbsp;`

  ```html
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #F6861F"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #DD1372"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #41AD49"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #00AAC0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #D32027"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #F49AC1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #EBB700"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #00ADE4">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  ```
- Using `height` attribute

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #F6861F" />
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #DD1372" />
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #41AD49" />
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #00AAC0" />
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #D32027" />
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #F49AC1" />
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #EBB700" />
  <div class="col-md-1" style="height: 20px; background-color: #00ADE4" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #F6861F"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #DD1372"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #41AD49"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #00AAC0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #D32027"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #F49AC1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #EBB700"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #00ADE4">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well this gets rid of the black dot but it adds the text ````&nbsp```` in place of the black dot. I don't want anything there at all. Just the blue col-md-1.

Comment: Oh I see, you forgot the semicolon at the end. Thank you. If you accept the edits that have been made to your answer I will give you credit.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please explain your code to make it useful for others. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer https://stackoverflow.com/tour. Please also test the code to make sure it actually works.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the entity for this character: ■. As the text colour is black, it is showing a black box.

You can replace `&#9632;` with `&nbsp;`, which is a space. With your code, it would look like:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #F6861F"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #DD1372"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #41AD49"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #00AAC0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #D32027"></div>
  <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: #F49AC1"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #EBB700"></div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="background-color: #00ADE4">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```